# Simple Python Server - How to prevent sending 304 on either end?

Tags: python, json, http, status

I set up a local simple http server in python on windows.

I set up an HTML file with javascript that uses setInterval() to request a JSON in the local directory every second. (Then updates the webpage with json content.)

Great, this works. Until after 15-60 seconds, the browser stops making requests, based on the server log in the terminal. The response 304 always precedes the break.

How can I avoid this and force the server always serve the json file every second?

Very new to this attempt and had to do tricks to make the browser even make the requests for local jsons or so due to security protocols. In part why the server is necessary, as via file:/// it can't be done.

My thought is change something in the server so if it wants to respond with 304, it will give a 200. I hope if it's always 200, the browser won't pause requests.

My other thought is ensure the json is always changing, hopefully avoiding the idea of it cached.

Comment: How are we supposed to know what "a local simple http server" is??  Is this code you wrote yourself?  Is it a free application you downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the browser’s console? What “tricks” did you use? Ideally, show the relevant code.

Comment: from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHabdler, test
import sys
class CORSRequestHandler (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler): def end_headers (self): sefl.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*') SinpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self) if __name__ == '__main__': test(CORSRequestHandler, HTTPServer, port=int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 8000)

Comment: @JohnGordon above comment is the python server code. As Stated, it is a "Simple" (I mean that literally) http server that is in the native/default python library

Comment: @Ry- the code is in a commrnt above, yes it is that short, although newline and tabbing couldn't be included. My tricks were to change something on browser security side about CORS to permit the unsafe request for files or something like that. Maybe it was server side, IDK. When I have time to recreate allll my steps I can do so, but probably googling how to get around CORS blocking requests might find what I did.  As to errors in console? The only one is a warning as I set browser to refuse localhost cookies in an attempt to force requesting every second. Console shows my .log otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your issue is related to caching. The browser is receiving a 304 response from the server, indicating that the content has not been modified since the last request, so it's using the cached version instead of making a new request.

To force the browser to always fetch the JSON file from the server instead of using the cache, you can try to disable caching on the server side. You can modify your Python HTTP server to include headers that prevent caching. You can do this by setting the [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers to no-cache.

```
import sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test


class CORSRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.end_headers(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test(CORSRequestHandler, HTTPServer, port=int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 8000)
```

In my understanding it looks something like this:
**main.py**

```
import os
import sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler


class CORSRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def end_headers(self):
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        super().end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/data.json':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
            self.end_headers()
            with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data.json'), 'rb') as file:
                self.wfile.write(file.read())
        else:
            super().do_GET()


def run_server(port):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CORSRequestHandler)
    print(f"Server running on port {port}")
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 8000
    run_server(port)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>JSON</h1>
    <div id="my-content"></div>
    <script>
        function fetchData() {
            fetch('http://localhost:8000/data.json')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    document.getElementById('my-content').innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
        }

        setInterval(fetchData, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was not clear to me on any other cache-control answer I can put that setting server side, as the other suggestions were it being anti-scraping measures of a client with no control over the server.

Comment: Stuck on this answer. I made the line self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'no-cache', '*') and get an error on thr server about giving 4 arguments when only 3 expected. How do I merge the Access Control Allow Origin and No Cache together?

Comment: I tried literally '(Access-Control-Allow-Origin, no-cache','*') But it is still responding with a 304 and the time between re-requests is growing. It's not 6 seconds apart. And now 7.

Comment: I tried for ...Origin,Cache Control: no-cache','*') and still no change, getting the string of 304s and for the longer the sequence of 304s, the longer the time before browser re-requests

Comment: After running for 20 minutes, the time between requests (or at least what is logged in the terminal running the python server) is nearly 2 minutes apart. The html file loaded in browser shows in the console my debug logs appearing every second, and no errors.

Comment: @Zyst Hi, you tried to pass 4 args (self, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'no-cache', '\*') whereas only 3 are expected (self,  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'). I updated the answer with code from yours. I hope it helps.

Comment: That is helpful, I did not even think about multiple headers like that, I would have thought the function had to respond with one full and complete answer. Seeing self.send-header() being called twice in a row with different parameters is so simple, I hope that is indeed all I need. And I can see why it being so simple I struggled to find that answer; people versed in servers would already know you can call multiple send_header()s